# How can I invert mui circular progress bar rotation direction?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change mui progress bar roation direction form left to right

I tried doing

```
    transform: rotate(180deg);
```

and I had no outcome

Comment: Please add more code to make a functional example so we can better understand your issue; and perhaps reproduce it right here IN the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Set the scale attribute to "-1 1" like so:

```
<CircularProgress sx={{ scale: "-1 1" }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `style={{transform: 'scaleX(-1) rotate(-90deg'}}`

```
<CircularProgress 
    style={{transform: 'scaleX(-1) rotate(-90deg'}} 
    size={'120px'} 
    variant="determinate">
</CircularProgress>
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess `transform: scale(-1)`?